# Powershell read filenames under folder and read each file content to create menu items

Tags: arrays, powershell, menu, switch-statement

I've a folder called c:\mycommands
files under this folder are multiple files like:
command1.txt
command2.txt
command3.txt

each file has one line only, like this:
in file command1.txt:
echo "this is command1"

in file command2.txt"
echo "this is command2"

and so on

I want to read the filename and it's content into an array/variable pair in order to build a dynamic menu.

so theoretically, all I would need to do in the future is to, drop a file into the folder and program will include it as menu option dynamically. (or remove the file to have it not show up in menu option.

What's the best way to approach this? maybe a do while loop with get-content into an array? Any input would be greatly appreciated. I'm really trying limit or avoid menu maintenance but would rather have the menu bre created dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three variations on the same basic idea, depending on what kind of output you need.

```
# Storing output in a hash table (key/value pairs)
$resultHash = @{}
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mycommands -File |
    ForEach-Object {$resultHash.Add($_.Name, (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName))}


# Storing output in an array of psobjects
$resultArray = @()
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mycommands -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
                        $resultArray += (New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{"NameOfFile"=$_.Name; "CommandText"=(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName);})
                    }


# Outputting psobjects to the pipeline
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\mycommands -File | 
    ForEach-Object {
                        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{"NameOfFile"=$_.Name; "CommandText"=(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName);}
                }



# Making a nice menu out of the hash table version
$promptTitle = "My menu"
$promptMessage = "Choose from the options below"
$promptOptions = @()
foreach ($key in $resultHash.Keys)
{
    $promptOptions += New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $key, $resultHash[$key]
}
$promptResponse = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($promptTitle, $promptMessage, $promptOptions, 0)
```

Comment: Nice key/value pair, what I was looking for. I can get all the output at once with write-output $resultHash. ...but how do get each key/value pair individually using write-output or write-host ? (I'm building a menu, the option selected would be filename in the array and value pair will be the content of that particular file

Comment: You can index into the hash table with the name of the key: $resultHash[“command1”] should get you the value associated with command1, $resultHash[“command2”] the value associated with command2, and so forth.

Comment: I'm trying adapt this menu to use the $resultHash value/pair, any ideas (part1)

function myMenu
    {
param (
[string]$Title = 'Select Command'
)
cls
###### Here is where I need the filename to be dynamically created 
Write-Host $Title
Write-Host "1) Command Title1"
Write-Host "2) Command Title2"
Write-Host "3) Command Title3"
Write-Host "4) Command Title4"
Write-Host "5) Command Title5"
Write-Host "6) Command Title6"
Write-Host "7) Command Title7"
Write-Host "q) Quit"
}
do
{

Comment: #Second part

myMenu
$input = Read-Host "Select Check"
switch ($input)
####### Here is where I need the content of the file
{
'1'{
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command1.exe'+'"'
} '2' {
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command2.exe'+'"'
} '3' {
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command3.exe'+'"'
} '4' {
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command4.exe'+'"'
} '5' {
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command5.exe'+'"'
} '6' {
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command6.exe'+'"'
} '7' { 
$global:scriptcmd = ' "'+'Command7.exe'+'"'
} 'q' {
}
}
}until ($input -eq 'q')

Comment: If you're trying to make a menu, I'd recommend looking at [PSHostUserInterface.PromptForChoice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) instead of rolling your own with Read-Host and Write-Host. I added an example to my answer since it's easier to read code there than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you want correctly, this might be able to accomplish it for you.

If will gather a list of all the files in a folder, then get the content from each one and add them to an Array one by one.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Files = @(Get-ChildItem "C:\Logs\" | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | 
    Select-Object FullName)
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$List_Of_Commands = @()

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$File_Contents = @(Get-Content $File.FullName)

    foreach ($Content in $File_Contents) {
        $Array_Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Command' = $Content
        }
        $List_Of_Commands.Add($Array_Object) | Out-Null
    }
}

$List_Of_Commands
```

Comment: Yes, This will work :)
How do I reference a particular file name along with it's associated content?

Comment: Inside the file you would just need to add another part to the `PSCustomObject`. Something like `'File_Name = $File.FullName` should work

Comment: If you wanted only the name of the file, `(Split-Path $File.FullName -Leaf)`